# Copy logins and passwords from production server to other server

Tags: t-sql

I want to copy **Logins** and **Passwords** from source server (Production) to other server using Microsoft’s `sp_hexadecimal` and `sp_help_revlogin` but before executing that SP I want to make sure all logins and passwords remain intact in source server after execution.

I would appreciate your help in advance.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can backup database logins, they are stored in the `Master` database. You can backup this system database as you would any other of your user databases. Use the Management Studio GUI or via the "backup database.." TSQL syntax.

But see [Considerations for Backing Up the master Database](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191488.aspx)